# Ignite - Out of memory

Tags: ignite

Enviornment : Ignite-2.8.1, Java 11

I am getting out of memory for my application after few minutes of start. On analyzing heap dump created on OOM, I see millions of instances of class org.apache.internal.processors.continuous.GridContinuousMessage

I do not see any direct references of these from my code.

Please suggest. Attaching snapshot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a Continuous Query running, and it is too slow/hanging and not able to process notifications in time, leading to their pile-up.

Comment: I do not have any Continuous query running.

Comment: Just to add on, If I have 3 clients connected, then this OOM occurs only on 2, the third one does not see OOM, but works very slow though.

Comment: The heap dump suggests you do. What do you do? What's your load profile?

Comment: I have few clients which only queries data from Ignite cluster, and few clients which inserts data. The OOM is seen on query clients. 

I did not see any reference anywhere on class ContinuousQuery in my code though.

Comment: Maybe you forget to close cursors on some of the queries? Please check which are the root objects holding all these messages

Comment: Yes, I did not close a few cursors. Fixing those did resolve OOM issues. Thnx @alamar